# Laravel Elixir, error installing node-sass: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-elixir, node-sass

When trying to install the node dependencies on a Laravel project I get the error

> error installing node-sass: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80

I am not behind a proxy and I have tried a lot of solutions I found in other answers to make node understand that I am not using or need any proxy...

> npm config set proxy null npm config set https-proxy null
>
> npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
>
> npm config set strict-ssl false
>
> npm config rm proxy
>
> npm config rm https-proxy
>
> npm config set proxy false
>
> npm cache clean

[Here](http://pasted.co/9817633f) is the npm-debug.log after a npm install.

Any ideas? How can I check the proxy configuration that is being used by node to see if there is any problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found doing a...

> npm config list

That I still had an https proxy set that (don't know why) was not being deleted by...

> npm config delete https-proxy

So I went to the C:\Users\your-user-name.npmrc file and edited to remove the conflicting line. Hope helps somebody.